# How to increase the number of spark nodes?

Tags: docker, apache-spark, kubernetes

I have a spark configuration as :

```html
executor_cores = "4"
executor_memory = "15g"
executor_instances = "4"
"spark.driver.memory": "2g",
"spark.driver.cores": "2",
"spark.executor.cores": executor_cores,
"spark.executor.memory": executor_memory,
"spark.executor.instances": executor_instances,
```

Currently, my application runs on 2 spark nodes. But I want to scale out the number of nodes to be used up to 4. How can I modify my spark configurations to achieve that ?

Comment: If you are doubling your node count, you can simply double the executor count as well.

Comment: You might be confused between executor and node. You cannot increase your node, but only executor which may or may not increase nodes, as per your cluster size. Even if you double the executor number, memory and core, its up to spark whether its needs be to spawned on 4 node or 3 nodes or any. Yes eventually you can spawn, but for that you need to check one node conf (how much memory and core provided for one node), and based on that you can provide memory and core for executor (need total 4 executor) to make sure that it will spawn in 4 different nodes